# Move div like JQuery dialog without overriding window.onMouseMove

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm working on a framework at the moment, and I have this JQuery-like dialog that I want to be able to move around with the mouse.

The problem is that I am trying not to use any libraries on this project or override something the user may want to use.

If I just use the `onmousemove` attribute for the `div` and if the mouse leaves while still dragging it - it will stop moving. Is there a way to possibly temporally override `window.onmousemove` or some other answer?

Comment: Seeing as you've tagged this question with jQuery, why are you using `onmousemove` and not simply handling the event with jQuery instead?

Comment: JQuery was added automatically, but if you read the question, you would know the problem with that.

Comment: But as jQuery is there, why are you avoiding using it? Tagging the question with jQuery lets people know that you're happy to accept an answer which relies on jQuery.

Comment: I removed the tag, stack overflow added it automatically. I'm supposed to use 100% of my own code for this project.

Comment: you mean you do not hope to use any `lib`?

Comment: Yeah, that word slipped from my head when writing the question, thanks.

Comment: You can get coordinates of the mouse pointer and give that coordinates to your div's top and left positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is use the `window event listener` and set the `div` style position to `absolute`

**Pure JS**

```
var m = document.getElementById('move');

m.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);

function mouseUp()
{
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
}

function mouseDown(e){
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
}

function move(e){
  m.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
  m.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="move" >XXXX</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid;
    position:absolute
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/3wTG4/3/)

Comment: `window.addEventListener()` is what I've been looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using client's mouse pointer's coordinates, you can move the element with the mouse:

```
var x = window.event.clientX, y = window.event.clientY;

var div = document.getElementById("your_div_id");

div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.top = y;
div.style.left = x;
```

Note:
when coordinates + div's dimensions, are higher than window's dimensions, you will have to subtract div's dimensions from x and y so that div will be show upper the pointer or left from the pointer in that case. That is when mouse at very most bottom or most right.